# WebRootPath is null in ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

Having no prior experience with .NET (7.0) i have created a clean ASP.NET MVC application using

```
dotnet new mvc -n MyApp
```

Now i need the application to read and write some PDF-files inside wwwroot (user uploads PDF and gets a modifed PDF in return).

I have injected it in the default `HomeController` like

```
private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    _env = env;
}
```

I have also included `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting`.

When trying to use the `WebRootPath` like

```
var outputPath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "output.pdf");
```

the `_env.WebRootPath` is `null` and the `_env.ContentRootPath` is `C:/.../MyApp/bin/Debug/net7.0` and not `C:/.../MyApp` like i would expect.

What am i missing? Shouldn't this work out of the box?

Comment: I would never put any data inside a web-accessible path. Instead, why not specify a path in your "appsettings.json" and use that one in your application? E.g. something like "C:\Data\MyApp".

Comment: ContentRootPath is executable part of your application. Your app is not deployed - you are using debug mode. And I would go with previous comment and place the  uploaded files somewhere in C:\Data\MyApp

Comment: How did you start the app? I can't reproduce your problem and could you provide a more detailed process so that we can troubleshoot.

Comment: I started it using the "play"-button in the visual studio toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve it by using the template `ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)` in the Visual Studio "Create a new project"-wizard instead of using `dotnet new mvc`.

Not sure what caused the original issue though, but i suspect it lies somewhere in the differences between the default configurations created by the wizard's template and `dotnet new mvc`.